# Train model to detect only 1 class label

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to train a model to see if the image is dog or not dog only, by implementing Sigmoid Activation Function in the output layer.

However normally, we can only put 2 train dataset (dog vs cat, dog vs cow), now I want to detect (dog vs all), so is there any way to do that? As if we detect dog vs cat, then in case I test with a human face, it could be possibly classified as dog at the end...

I tried with Keras, but seems impossible now.

I do not know why in object detection, we can train a model with only 1 class label needed and it doesnt classify any unrelated objects as the one we want to train on (like we only detect dogs in an image, and then books, humans are also detected as dogs).

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is that your target feature has multiple classes such as Dog, Cow, Cat etc. and you want to classify the images as Dog vs Not Dog, then you could just change the labels in your dataframe.

1 for images of dogs.

0 for all other images.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but there are many image topic like human, dog, cat, car... i dont think we can collect them all just for 0. Do you have any idea?